# Return row with latest "effective_date" in mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Having trouble connecting the dots on this by looking at other examples.  Looking for some help in writing this so that it only pulls back the most recent entry for each 9DVN: That is, pull back one row of data with the most recent effective date.

```
    SELECT b.vndr_name AS Supplier,
           a.VENDOR_NBR*1000 + a.VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + a.VENDOR_SEQ_NBR AS "9DVN", 
           a.VENDOR_NBR AS "6DVN",a.VENDOR_DEPT_NBR AS "Dept", 
           a.VENDOR_SEQ_NBR AS "Seq" ,a.FREIGHT_FACTOR_PCT AS "Rate",
           a.Effective_Date AS "Effect Date",
           a.LAST_CHANGE_USERID AS "By",
           COUNT(a.DC_NBR) AS "DC Count"
  FROM MainTable.DC_FRT_FCTR a
  INNER JOIN SecondaryTable ON b.vndr_nbr = a.vendor_nbr
  ORDER BY a.Effective_Date DESC
  GROUP BY B.vndr_name, 
  a.VENDOR_NBR, 
  a.VENDOR_DEPT_NBR, 
  a.VENDOR_SEQ_NBR,  
  a.FREIGHT_FACTOR_PCT, 
  Effective_Date, 
  a.LAST_CHANGE_USERID
```

Comment: Does your `DC_FRT_FCTR` table have a single column identifying distinct `9DVN` values?

Comment: This question has been answered hundreds of times under the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The 9dvn is a concatenation of three fields

Answer (score 0):

This is a common query pattern: finding the detail row associated with an extreme value of a particular column.

You need a subquery to find the extreme value -- in your case the latest effective date -- for each vendor. Something like this:

```
                   SELECT MAX(Effective_Date) Effective_Date,
                          VENDOR_NBR*1000 + VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + VENDOR_SEQ_NBR "9DVN"  
                     FROM DC_FRT_FCTR 
                 GROUP BY VENDOR_NBR*1000 + VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + VENDOR_SEQ_NBR
```

You should test this subquery to make sure it yields sane results.

Then you need to join it into the rest of your query on the extreme value, like so.

```
   SELECT b.vndr_name AS Supplier,
          a.VENDOR_NBR*1000 + a.VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + a.VENDOR_SEQ_NBR AS "9DVN", 
          ...etc...
          COUNT(a.DC_NBR) AS "DC Count"
     FROM MainTable.DC_FRT_FCTR a
     JOIN (
                   SELECT MAX(Effective_Date) Effective_Date,
                          VENDOR_NBR*1000 + VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + VENDOR_SEQ_NBR "9DVN"  
                     FROM DC_FRT_FCTR 
                 GROUP BY VENDOR_NBR*1000 + VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + VENDOR_SEQ_NBR
          ) latest 
              ON latest.9DVN = a.VENDOR_NBR*1000 + a.VENDOR_DEPT_NBR*10 + a.VENDOR_SEQ_NBR
             AND latest.Effective_Date = a.Effective_Date
     JOIN SecondaryTable b 
              ON b.vndr_nbr = a.vendor_nbr
 ORDER BY a.Effective_Date DESC
 GROUP BY B.vndr_name, 
          ... etc ...
```